# IAM user with full S3 access cannot download file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've created an S3 bucket with my administrator account, and I've created an IAM user (programmatic access only). I've uploaded a dummy txt file (as admin), and I'm using python boto3 to download this file, but I get an `Access denied` exception.

I have no clear idea why, since it's a very simple setup.

My python code:

```
import os
import boto3
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# load environment variables
load_dotenv()

boto_session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_ID'), aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY'), region_name=os.getenv('AWS_REGION'))
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('dev-tom', 'readme.txt', f)
```

The credentials in the environment are correct for the IAM user, I've checked.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 678, in download_fileobj
    return future.result()
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py", line 343, in _submit
    **transfer_future.meta.call_args.extra_args
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

My bucket has no policy attached, so it's the default.

My IAM user config:

[image: Nothing special, full access]

My file details:

[image: File configuration]

Comment: what is your s3 bucket permission?

Comment: The standard environment variables are named `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`. There's no need for you to invent a new set of environment variables. If you use the defaults then you don't even need to fetch them -- boto3 (and all SDKs) will fetch them for you.

Comment: @JackYu Thanks, but it's no longer necessary.. made a silly programming assumption which was wrong (the bucket is 'public is allowed', that's all)

Comment: @jarmod I load these from a .env file instead of relying on the ones in my shell environment (since they'll be loaded on a server)

Comment: Note: if your server is EC2 (or Lambda or ECS) then you shouldn't have any files containing credentials. You should instead use IAM roles to provide credentials to the instance. But I don't know your environment, so this may not be relevant.

Comment: @jarmod nope just a regular old server calling an AWS service

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, my issue is not at all with the bucket or its permissions...

This line ignores all previous session things I set up:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

And just takes whatever access credentials it can find on the environment, which were set to another IAM user that had *no* full s3 access.

(One of) the correct solutions is to just:

```
s3 = boto_session.client('s3')
```

I should learn to program, that is all.